Rock Paper Scissors Turns Countdown and Score Counter
I have successfully created a rock paper scissors in Python but I'm having trouble when it comes to actually having the player play a best-of-7 game.
I would like for the game to run 7 times, count the scores (i.e. if the computer won, the player won or the game was a tie) and then tell those scores to the player at the end. The below code is just the game itself without any while loops to indicate turns since I couldn't get the turns system working.
Whenever I did get it correctly working, it would always instead of being a random choice (rock, paper or scissors) just choose whatever it chose first 7 times.
import random

choices = ["Rock", "Scissors", "Paper"]
choice = random.choice(choices)

#     should i put a while loop in game() or outside? neither make the choice random, it's always whatever the computer chose first


def game():
    prompt = input("Rock, paper or scissors?: ").title()
    match prompt:
        case "Rock":
            if choice == "Paper":
                print("Paper, I win!")
            if choice == "Scissors":
                print("Scissors, you win!")
        case "Paper":
            if choice == "Scissors":
                print("Scissors, I win!")
            if choice == "Rock":
                print("Rock, you win!")
        case "Scissors":
            if choice == "Rock":
                print("Rock, I win!")
            if choice == "Paper":
                print("Paper, you win!")
    if choice == prompt:
        print(f"{choice}, Tie!")


game()


You are calling random.choice(choices) only once, outside the loop. If you want it to generate a random choice every turn, you have to  move it inside the look.

Yep, basically you've implemented this famous cartoon. The choice is not random anymore after it has been set.

I recommended to use a loop and store each result in a list and at last count 0 or 1 assign 0 for computer win else 1 if 0 count is greater computer wins else human win. If both 0 and 1 are equal then tie

Hi ars and welcome. This answer is unclear to me, and it misses the issue mentioned in the comments. Please try and edit it in!
